# Different composition for 9 marbles in 6 boxes (not more than 3 per box)

Tags: combinatorics

I have 9 marbles, which are randomly put, one by one, in 6 different boxes. Each box has equally chance of receive the marble. A box can be empty at the end, but will never contains more than 3 marbles. If a box with 3 marbles is chosen, then another box is selected, repeated until a box with less than 3 marbles is selected.

My question is, how can I determine every solution, and the different combinations for each solution. I found these results, but I really am not sure of what I found:

`3-3-3-0-0-0` : ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ combinations
`3-3-2-1-0-0` : ${6 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 1} = 180$
`3-3-1-1-1-0` : ${6 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 3} = 60$
`3-2-2-2-0-0` : ${6 \choose 1} \cdot {5 \choose 3} = 60$
`3-2-2-1-1-0` : ${6 \choose 1} \cdot {5 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 2} = 180$
`3-2-1-1-1-1` : ${6 \choose 1} \cdot {5 \choose 1} = 30$
`2-2-2-2-1-0` : ${6 \choose 4} \cdot {2 \choose 1} = 30$
`2-2-2-1-1-1` : ${6 \choose 3} = 20$
`_t_o_t_a_l_` : $20 + 180 + 60 + 60 + 180 + 30 + 30 + 20 = 580$ combinations

---

Following question: assuming that previous results are corrects, is it true to say this?

> There is $\frac{20}{580}$ chance to get 3 boxes empty at the end.
>   There is $\frac{530}{580}$ chance to have at least one box with 3 marbles at the end.

Comment: If boxes are distinguishable and marbles are not then I cannot find a mistake in your result.

Comment: What do you mean by _boxes are distinguishable_? What would have changed if they weren't?

Comment: In that case there is only $1$ combination for e.g. $3-3-3-0-0-0$. In words: $3$ boxes are filled with $3$ balls and $3$ boxes are empty. That counts for one solution then.

Comment: Ok, so, they are. Thanks

Comment: It may help if you could clarify whether you are looking for finding the number of arrangements or for a listing of those arrangements (may require an algorithm).

Comment: I'd like to establish the chance a getting a specific pattern. Especially I want to know what are the chance to have at least one box with 3 marbles.

Comment: To answer probability questions, you will need to specify how the marbles got in the boxes.  For example, did someone throw each marble into a box chosen at random, with each box equally likely to be chosen, and it just happened that no box contained more than 3 marbles?

Comment: Box is chosen randomly. If the box already contains 3 marbles, Another box is chosen randomly. Repeat as many times as needed. Box have equally chance of being chosen, independently of their content.